# Fetching data from product table where category values are stored in serialize format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, serialization

While adding product in table_product, I have one column with name "category". At certain point I could have multiple category for any product, that's why I stored all category list in `serialize` format.

How can I fetch `product_name`, `product_image` and `product_id` from particular category?

Say like, I have this URL `http://www.example.com/category.php?cid=29`, So I want to display all the products from that particular category. Therefore I ran below command in `php-mysql`

```
"Select product_id, product_name, product_image from product where category='Select name from category where cid="29"';
```

And I am getting empty set. Because, `category` column in my `product table` is as below :-

`a:3:{i:0;s:5:"Apple";i:1;s:6:"Iphone";i:2;s:9:"Iphone 5S";}`

Any solution can work to solve my issue.

Pardon me for my bad english.

Comment: I don't think there's any clean way to do this, since MySQL knows nothing about PHP's serialize format. This is a horrible table design. If you need to allow multiple categories, you should use a relation table, not serialized PHP data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the categories as serialized data, use a relation table:

```
create table product_category (
    product_id int,
    category_id int);
```

Then to find the products in a particular category, you use a join:

```
select p.*
from product p
join product_category pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
where pc.category_id = 29;
```

This is how you should do many-to-many relationships in an RDBMS.

Comment: It's an alias for the `product` table. Any SQL tutorial should explain that.